# Change the state in a Vaadin custom widget in the connector through a GWT button click and get it server side

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin7, custom-widgets

I am trying to set the state in a Vaadin custom widget from a click generated by the user.  In the component connector after instantiating the server rpc I get the GWT button and add an onclick method.  In the method I set the state (getState.text = "new text";) but when I try to get it from the server side I get the original state text. The onStateChange method is not triggered.

Code in the connector:

```
        getWidget().getSaveButton().addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            alert("does it work without jquery?");
            getState().text = "text changed from connector";
            getWidget().getTextBox().setText(getState().text);
        }
    });
```

after clicking GWT button the textbox contains the text to "text changed from connector"

In the state:

```
public String text = "original state text";
```

The UI implementation to get the state:

```
vaadinButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Notification.show(sig.getState().text);

        }
    });
```

When clicking the vaadin button after clicking the GWT button the notification still displays "original state text".

My question:
How do I change the state in the connector so it triggers the onStateChange method and I get the text changes server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to update state from the client side. Only server can update state. You should do so that you sent a RPC request from client to server, and on the server you update the value to state.

Edit, here is an example on how to send a value from client to server using Vaadin's RPC mechanism:

Create an interface extending `ServerRpc`:

```
public interface MyServerRpc extends com.vaadin.shared.communication.ServerRpc {
  void setValue(String value)
}
```

Use a proxy created from the above interface to send value to server. This call is done inside the connector.

```
getRpcProxy(MyServerRpc.class).setValue("New value to server");
```

Register an interface implementation to your server-side component to receive RPC calls:

```
registerRpc(new MyServerRpc() {

  public void setValue(String value) {
    // set the value to state here by saying getState().myValue = value;
    // or do something else
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much Henri.  It has been a little while since I've seen you.  I'm the coffee spitter from the New York class

Comment: @FCoffee, hah, I hope that everything is going great there.

Comment: Things are going well. I haven't coughed any drinks on anyone since:)  The problem I want to solve is I am trying to get a json string back from the client side widget.  According to your answer I can't do this through the state.  Is the only way to do this pre-existing Vaadin Components? As in take the json string and place it in a Vaadin TextArea and then get the text Server Side.  I would probably place the custom widget inside a Composite Component with a TextArea.

Comment: You can use RPC for that. I editor the answer and added an example.

Comment: Your example helped me immensely. I am able to change the state.  Thank  you very much Henri.